# Use a "null" switch statement to determine if a range of TextBoxes are null, instead of using if-else statements

Tags: c#, textbox, null, switch-statement

At the moment, I am trying to write a method that has inside it a switch statement which uses as the "trigger" the reserved word null. This is because I want all the TextBoxes, in this switch statement to be tested for the state of being null, and if they are, a MessageDialog (which I've coded for each box) will appear saying that 'You cannot leave "insert name of TextBox here", blank. You must enter text'

In short, is it possible to use a switch statement to test if a bunch of TextBoxes are null, rather than using a whole sequence of (unwieldy) if-else statements? If so, how? (please)

I should add that I've been at this problem for the last hour and a half, with no success.

Any help is gratefully accepted.

Comment: A `switch` statement matches *one* `case` (or `default`). So the `switch` form would find *one* textbox that's blank but all textboxes further down in the switch would be ignored. Is that really what you're trying to do?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: To be honest, this sounds like a painful way to do it... You would be better off adding the validation to the "model" class for the form by implementing [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Hi. What I am trying to do, is have a whole series of text boxes checked for a "null" condition, without needing to use a whole bunch of if-else statements. So, I want for each case to ask "Is this TextBox null?" I do know how to to do this, but not in the format the "case" keyword requires.

Comment: But that's not what a `switch` does - as soon as it find a *single* `case` that matches, it enters the associated code block and then the `switch` exits - it doesn't carry on matching further `case`s.

Comment: Unless your using an array of textboxes using their index for the switch trigger and then using string.IsNullOrEmpty() for the content it may be possible but if not, just like Trover Pilley said it going to be painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifically want to use a `Switch`:

Make them into a `List` or an `Array`, if it is not that already.

```
List<string> TextBoxCollection = new List<string>();
TextBoxCollection.Add(yourTextBoxStringValue); //Do this for each of the boxes.
```

Then just iterate through the TextBoxCollection.

```
foreach (string textContent in TextBoxCollection)
{
    switch (textContent)
    {
        case null:
        {
            //Do the message error here.
            break;
        }
        case "otherRequirement":
        {
            //Do other stuff here.
            break;
        }
        case "anotherRequirement":
        case "oneMoreRequirement":
        {
            //Do different things here, maybe?
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This will iterate through the collection, and then test each string from it.

I would not recommend doing this, unless **all the text boxes' values have to be validated for multiple conditions, all the same**, in which case this will look more tidy than an If Else for each string value.

---

If you want a quick one line solution to check this for each one, you can just use:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yourTextBox.Text)) { //Throw error here. }
```

Comment: But that's just using `switch` for perversities sake. An `if` would be clearer here.

Comment: Just for the sake of using switch? as previously said if would be fine.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever True, but this is the best way of using a `Switch` for validation of null cases, which was requested by the OP.

Comment: @HowlinWulf How would I set up a TextBoxCollection? In the traditional manner of making a new object? I've never come across TextBoxCollection before, see. Many thanks for your solution.

Comment: @user3211967 Just make a List or an Array and use it, like I have put into my answer.

Comment: So, "yourTextBoxStringValue" is the identifier given to the text box, or is it the actual string value? Say: textBox1.Text = "test"

Comment: @user3211967 the actual string value, yes. it can be the text box itself, but then you will need to change the type of the `List`, and the data type pulled in the `foreach`, and then do the `.text` on each iteration in there.

It is easier to pull the text before you start iterating.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Create a method, which will loop over Controls recursively:

```
    public static void ForAllControls(this Control parent, Action<Control> action)
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {
            action(c);
            ForAllControls(c, action);
        }
    }
```

Create a method, which will validate the TextBox:

```
    public void validateTextBoxes(Control c)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)) 
            if(TextBox.Text == "") MessageBox.Show("insert name of TextBox here")
    }
```

Call the method, like this:

```
    this.ForAllControls(c => {
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)) validateTextBoxes(c);
        });
```

Or use `ErrorProvider.SetError();`

Answer (score 0):

This may not be using switch but it will save you some lines.

```
public static void IsTxtNull(Textbox xTxt, string msg)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(xTxt.Text)
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

Then call it like this

```
IsTxtNull(YourTxtBox1,"Message for YourTxtBox1");
IsTxtNull(YourTxtBox2,"Message for YourTxtBox2");
IsTxtNull(YourTxtBox3,"Message for YourTxtBox3");
etc...
```